# What is correct sql connection string?

Tags: sqlconnection, .net-core-2.2

I'm trying to run a .net core 2.2 web api on Debian 9. It works fine on my local machine (macOS) but after publishing it to Debian it shows error:

```
"ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'datasource'"
 System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary<string, string> parsetable, string connectionString, bool buildChain, Dictionary<string, string> synonyms, bool firstKey)
```

while accessing to a MSSql database on Windows machine.

I tried two connection strings in appsettings.json file.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=Server_IP;Database=Database_Name;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=User_ID;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
```

and

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Server_IP;Initial Catalog =Database_Name;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=User_ID;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
```

I could connect from Debian to MSSql serwer using mssql-cli command.
What is the reason that dotnet app cant parse connection string?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was wrong working dir in kestrel service.

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/application_path/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /application_path/execute_package.dll
```